# Keep loop running but continue code after in rails startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a couple of loops in my rails framework that I'd need to RUN in the background. I tried to put the code in config/application.rb and in config/initializers but it halted the execution in the loop and didn't really start the server because I couldn't access localhost:gate. So what I'd like to do is run these processes on the background and still initialize the server in localhost:gate. How to do this? Tyvm

Comment: Create a `rake` task in your `lib/tasks` and run that simultaneously with the rails server

Comment: @nik but do I manually have to start them? Can't I just run 'rails s' and start it all?

Comment: Cron job in rails does what you want. Here check the [link](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/cron-jobs-and-rails)

Comment: @nik It's not a cron job. It's a stream.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you looking for background job and you can do simply with sidekiq put your loop or whatever piece of code you need to run in a worker and execute it every x seconds in clock.rb.

checkout sidekiq:

http://sidekiq.org

Comment: and its companion, sidetiq.